# How to translate A-Frame dynamic body

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr, oculus

I'm making an A-Frame project which will allow users to interact with math models. I'm using the `aframe-super-hands-component` with `aframe-physics-extras` for its nice "sleep" effect. To add a layer of control, I'm trying to make it so that the user can use a controller's joysticks to bring a model closer/farther away from the controller, similar to the Oculus Dash controls (https://youtu.be/sMjlM5vFSA0?t=1m55s).

However, when I try to update a model's position, as my model entities are defined as dynamic bodies, they don't move. I know that I can remove the `dynamic-body` component, move the body, and then reattach `dynamic-body`, but I want to avoid that as I'm planning to move models in `tick`. Is there a way I can move a dynamic body without breaking `dynamic-body` behavior?

Here's a link to an example which tries to update a box's position: https://codepen.io/kchen1250/pen/MBmRYo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sync the position of the entity and the `dynamic-body` using the `dynamic-body`s method `syncToPhysics()`

```
el.components["dynamic-body"].syncToPhysics()
```

like i did [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vamwwW).

---

There is also an analogous `syncFromPhysics()` if you'd ever need it.

Comment: I tried this, and it kinda works. In my main project where I can grab an object with a controller, the object does try to move, but can't get very far: https://imgur.com/a/AfzmwzL

Comment: Update: I think your answer is right, i think the weird behavior above is caused by the `super-hands` grab event being triggered while trying to update the position

Comment: Follow up question: any way to supress super-hand's grab to move a grabbed object?

Comment: @kchen1250 i'm quite unable to test the super hands right now, id suggest making a new question for this matter

Comment: @PaulSlm glad I could help :)